# How to resolve CORS issue in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I try to use js code to fetch the remote(spring boot) js code and it shows

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://45.82.79.208/ with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details
```

My js code:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://45.82.79.208/";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

My spring boot code, allow cros:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")  // allow cros path
        .allowedOrigins("*")    // allow cros origin
        .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")// allow method
        .maxAge(168000) //
        .allowedHeaders("*")
        .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with my code? How can I solve this issue to allow CORS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [the page](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers), the response type is not correct. You can try to set the response header (content-type) of the js

**it will block a cross-origin text/html response requested from a  or  tag, replacing it with an empty response instead**

Comment: I modify the code , and force it to produce "application/javascript", and  it works

Answer (score 0):

Enabling CORS is straightforward – just add the annotation @CrossOrigin to your controllers.
Please check this website for more details : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors